# Reading from option value and creating link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have some options which have some values

```
<option value = "google.com"></option>
 <option value = "yahoo.com"></option>
 <option value = "linkedin.com"></option>
```

I know that I can take this value and display it as text. (I can convert the value into an h5,h4 etc. But is it possible to make an href redirecting to the value of the option? Of course I can just manually make `<a href = "google.com">`, but I was just wondering if this was possible

**TLDR**

Given an option html element, take the value display it on the screen as a link.

I would never do this, but a colleague asked me how to do this today, and I couldnt really think of a way off the top oh my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will create a link out of the values of all the options with the link name.

```
$("option").each(function(){
 $(this).html('<a href="' + $(this).val() + '">link Name</a>');
});
```

You would of course have to come up with your own text for the anchor tag, and I'm not sure where you would get that based on the snippet you provided.